# Enlarge a view using a zoom animation

Tags: java, android

If you please, I will quote the proposed solution in the developer page for Android The solution is how to enlarge the image when you click it But after applying it and when I click on the image the application closes and gives me an error occurred This is a picture of the error tracker Can anyone help me solve the problem

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom

I have resubmitted the question after adding files xml and java

Sample of XML file containing 100 images for viewing

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/photo_1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/allah_jl_jlalh"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
            app:civ_border_width="3dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/photo_2"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/alrahman"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
            app:civ_border_width="3dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/photo_3"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/alrahem"
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
            app:civ_border_width="3dp"
            tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

    </LinearLayout>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
```

java file:

```
public class Athkar7 extends AppCompatActivity {
private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

private int mShortAnimationDuration;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_athkar7 );

    final CircleImageView thumb1View = (CircleImageView) findViewById( R.id.photo_1 );
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb( thumb1View,R.drawable.alrahman );
        }
    } );

    // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime );
}
public void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView,int imageResId) {
    // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
    // immediately and proceed with this one.
    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(
            R.id.expanded_image );
    expandedImageView.setImageResource( imageResId );

    // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
    // This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
    // and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container
    // view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
    // bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
    // properties (X, Y).
    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect( startBounds );
    findViewById( R.id.container )
            .getGlobalVisibleRect( finalBounds,globalOffset );
    startBounds.offset( -globalOffset.x,-globalOffset.y );
    finalBounds.offset( -globalOffset.x,-globalOffset.y );

    // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
    // bounds using the "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable
    // stretching during the animation. Also calculate the start scaling
    // factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).
    float startScale;
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
            > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
        // Extend start bounds horizontally
        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {
        // Extend start bounds vertically
        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }

    // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
    // begins, it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the
    // thumbnail.
    thumbView.setAlpha( 0f );
    expandedImageView.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );

    // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations
    // to the top-left corner of the zoomed-in view (the default
    // is the center of the view).
    expandedImageView.setPivotX( 0f );
    expandedImageView.setPivotY( 0f );

    // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
    // scale properties (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set
            .play( ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( expandedImageView,View.X,
                    startBounds.left,finalBounds.left ) )
            .with( ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( expandedImageView,View.Y,
                    startBounds.top,finalBounds.top ) )
            .with( ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( expandedImageView,View.SCALE_X,
                    startScale,1f ) )
            .with( ObjectAnimator.ofFloat( expandedImageView,
                    View.SCALE_Y,startScale,1f ) );
    set.setDuration( mShortAnimationDuration );
    set.setInterpolator( new DecelerateInterpolator() );
    set.addListener( new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
    } );
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;

    // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down
    // to the original bounds and show the thumbnail instead of
    // the expanded image.
    final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
            }

            // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
            // back to their original values.
            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set.play( ObjectAnimator
                    .ofFloat( expandedImageView,View.X,startBounds.left ) )
                    .with( ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat( expandedImageView,
                                    View.Y,startBounds.top ) )
                    .with( ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat( expandedImageView,
                                    View.SCALE_X,startScaleFinal ) )
                    .with( ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat( expandedImageView,
                                    View.SCALE_Y,startScaleFinal ) );
            set.setDuration( mShortAnimationDuration );
            set.setInterpolator( new DecelerateInterpolator() );
            set.addListener( new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha( 1f );
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha( 1f );
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility( View.GONE );
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }
            } );
            set.start();
            mCurrentAnimator = set;
        }
        } );
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LN6CI.jpg)

This code is to be applied to 100 images that you have set for viewing within a single activity
Here I have another problem that when I pass the application slider suddenly comes out of the activity and returns to the MainActivity how can I solve this problem ???

Answer (score 0):

Use this [library](https://github.com/imablanco/Zoomy) to solve your problem.